# Best way to prevent Flutter Flat Button from wrapping text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have experienced that Flat buttons with Text widgets inside of them often wrap onto a second line, making for a very ugly button that looks like this

Cance
l

What is the best way of making sure this text does not wrap?

Comment: How would you like the text to behave, instead of wrapping?

Comment: Continue until it reaches the end of the available space. Ideally resize its font to fit.

Comment: To be honest it would not be a very good user experience. If you had a very long sentence the font could be so small that users wouldn't be able to read it. Can you give a screenshot example of what you have and why you don't to cut it off or expand vertically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 FlatButton(
  color: Colors.yellow,
  onPressed: _onPressed,
  child: Text(
    "Click Here",
    softWrap: false,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
)
```

Set `softWrap` to `false` to avoid single-line statement wraps on insufficient space.
Set `overflow` to indicate the overflowed text (See [TextOverflow Values](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/TextOverflow-class.html))
Set `maxLines` to 1 when your text has multiple lines like `Hello \n World`

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution to that is to just use the AutoSizeText Widget from the auto_size_text package in the dart library. (https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text). Then it will simply adjust its font size depending of the available space.

Answer (score 0):

May need to adjust padding or use softWrap: false. This will make the text cut off rather than wrap.

```
Text(Constants.SHARE_LABEL, softWrap: false)
```